# Submitting my property for section 8

Tags: united-states, rental-property, housing, landlord

I have a tenant who wasn't section 8 qualified when they started renting from me. The main breadwinner however has just passed away and the remaining family members (spouse and kids) now qualify for section 8.

I have never submitted this property to HUD for qualifying. I know nothing about this. What are the steps for doing this and is it something I can do while it is rented?

**About the rental:**
Newly remodeled, 4 bedroom, 2 1/2 bath, 1600 square ft house w/Garage and 1 office
Located in Montana
Rents for $1200 a month

Comment: Zillow has a good article [here](http://www.zillow.com/blog/pro/getting-your-property-qualified-for-section-8-1513/) on how to get started.

Answer (score 1):

A quality rental should not have any problem getting qualified for section 8 and yes, you can qualify while the tenant is currently renting. Although the process is kind of slow and may take a month or 2 to actually complete and begin receiving payments from section 8.

Good luck